# Decrease in mathematical creativity due to weed

Tags: lasting-effects-duration, cognitive-science, marijuana, irreversible-damage, brain-damage

I had been smoking cannabis since last year and I think I've undergone a decrease in mathematical creativity.

I used to get a lot of ideas about how to tackle a math problem and was a somewhat good problem solver.

But now, after 8-9 months of cannabis usage, I get stuck at the most basic problems and am unable to solve if I haven't solved it before.

Is this just my anxiety that's causing it or is this for real?

Can quitting cannabis restore my abilities to some extent?

P.s - This is not some anti-weed propaganda. I'm really feeling like this for some time now.

Comment: Until I can collect some studies of the subject, my advice would be this:  states of mind are tools, and should be used as such.  There are several techniques to improve concentration and conceptualization of mathematical and similarly discrete problems.  From my observations, cannabis doesn't make people into stoners:  it increases the appeal of certain activities and lifestyles, and it is the habituation with those activities which produces the malaise linked with cannabis use or misuse.